# Can't initialize popovers in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on someone else angular application. I'm trying to add a popover. The html is in a ng-include template and has a tag:

```
<p class="filetracker-label" data-toggle="popover" title="title is here!" data-content="popOver on bottom">Tracked Files</p>
```

and I initialized popovers in the body tag (bootstrap.js and jquery are in the head tag - I've moved them, but it doesn't change anything):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement: 'left',
        trigger : 'hover'
    });
    console.log('here');
});
</script>
```

I load jquery before bootstrap - I've researched all the other posts on this, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I see the title text when I hover, but it is not bootstrap styled - and of course the content isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to do Angular and Bootstrap, I would suggest using UI Bootstrap which is Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS.

The documentation for popovers with UI Bootstrap is here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/53/

Looks like the popover is hidden in the page as you have set it's placement as 'Left'. Set the width of the 'Tracked Files' text and change it's placement to bottom, the popover will appear.

JS

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        trigger : 'hover'
});
```

HTML

```
<p class="filetracker-label" data-toggle="popover" title="title is here!" data-content="popOver on bottom">Tracked Files</p>
```

CSS

```
.filetracker-label{
width:100px;
}
```

Comment: this is verbatim what I have already - I see your fiddle works, of course.  Unfortunately it doesn't help my problem - although it means its probably because I am not including some information that is necessary. Sadly, I don't know what else could be relevant at this point...

Comment: Try changing the placement from left to bottom. If it still does not show up, the problem could be somewhere else in you code.

Comment: that doesn't do anything - i wouldn't expect it to, since placement is a feature of the bootstrap styling that isn't working at all. I realize the problem is probably somewhere else, but it's not my code, and I have no idea what to look for. :( thanks for your help though.

Comment: Hi Vinesh, I figured my problem out - I upvoted your comment - thanks for trying to help - I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it actually.  The popover initialization needs to be inside the angular controller for that part of the app.  Kind of obvious in retrospect, since the html get injected after an ajax request, which is after the document ready function has already fired.  New to angular...